# Copy files instead of move for external SSD - how to restore default behavior

Tags: ssd, external-disk

I have an external SSD that MOVES files instead of copying when I drag them off the disk. Usually, I would expect to hold `command` for a move. How can I restore the default behavior of copying instead of moving?

When I view the disk in disk utility, it shows the format `CoreStorage Logical Volume`. The disk is encrypted. I also recall in the past being asked to enter my system password when moving files off the disk.